# add client certificate before posting to https server in C++

Tags: http-post, client-certificates

I want to post some data to a https server before which I need to add a client certificate for  trust validation. I have already done it in C# which is as follows:-

```
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("Path to my .cer file");   //****** name of cer file is "ServerTrial.cer" ******//
Uri authURL = new Uri("https://myServer/post");
HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authURL);    //****** Here i add the server url ******//
authRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);    //****** Here i add the client certificate ******//
authRequest.Method = "POST";    //****** Here i specify the method which is "POST" ******//

byte[] postBytes = "Data to be posted";
authRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream();
// now send it
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);   //****** Here I post the data to the Server ******//
requestStream.Close();

// grab the response
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();      
StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseStr = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

So ultimately what i want is to create a http object, add the server url to it, add the client certificate to it and then finally post the data to the server.
Now i want to achieve the above in C++. I am thinking of using openSSL for the above but I have very less idea of it. Can anyone please guide me regarding this?

-Thanking everyone,
sattu